# Repeating a loop with linked variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sets of variables `a1-a5, b1-b5, c1-c5` (5 variables per set).

`a1`, `b1`, and `c1` are linked and need to be used together in a loop. What I am trying to do is something along the lines of

```
Do While
' Loop using variables a1,b1,c1
Loop
```

I want to then repeat this loop with `a2,b2,c2, etc.`

So within my loop I am searching for the position of string `a1` within a range specified elsewhere - let's call that `Pos`.
I then add `a2` (a number) to `Pos`.
`a3` is another number used elsewhere in the loop. 
`a2` and `a3` change depending on what the string in `a1` is, hence having to use them together.

I'm fairly new to `VBA` so the simpler the better!

Thanks

Comment: You can simple write Do While i < 6 and concatenate i with your variables.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. I have the impression that there is some central variable, let's call it `t`, and all your mentioned variables depend on it. Can you give some more information on what exactly you want to achieve and what you've already tried to achieve it?

Comment: So within my loop I am searching for the position of **string a1** within a range specified elsewhere - let's call that Pos.

I then add **a2** (a number) to Pos.

**a3** is another number used elsewhere in the loop.

a2 and a3 change depending on what the string in a1 is, hence having to use them together.

Comment: Sounds to me that you should have a look at [arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)

Comment: I can't visualise what you mean.  You're searching for the position of a string in the variable `a1` within a range specified elsewhere - what range and where and can  you provide an example.  Is `Pos` the reference to the range?  You then add a number to `Pos` - add it as in `1+3 = 4`, or `1 & 1 = 11`.  Too many questions ... can you draw us a nice clear picture of how this works?  [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) is a good tool for laying out tables in your question.

Comment: Could you also edit any extra info into your original question please - the edit button is under the tags.

Answer (score 1):

@Stefan Fidlschuster i dont fully understand you question but i believe that this will help:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim Address As Range
Dim A1Value As String
Dim Pos As Range
Dim A2Addition As Integer

With wsTest

    Set Pos = .Columns("F:F") '<= Search area (In the example is column F)

    For i = 1 To 5
         A1Value = .Range("A" & i).Value '<= Value in cell A1

         Set Address = Pos.Find(What:=A1Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

         A2Addition = Address.Row + .Range("B" & i).Value

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group variables together and loop, you can use `Type`.

```
Type abc
    a As String
    b As Long
    c As Long
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim abcs(1 To 5) As abc, abci As abc
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        abci = abcs(i)
        ' Use abci.a, abci.b, abci.c here
    Next i
End Sub
```

But that said, it's hard to understand what you're trying to do and you should post some example data.

Comment: Did you test your code `abc(i)`? throws "sub or function not defined".

Comment: Yea it should be `abcs(i)`. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays

```
Dim a(1 To 5) As Long 'define your desired type if not Long
Dim b(1 To 5) As Long 
Dim c(1 To 5) As Long 

Do While x
    a(1) = 5
    b(1) = 10
    '…
Loop


Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5
    a(i) = i * 2
    b(i) = i * 3
Next i
```