# Loop numbered variables in Excel VBA -

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, variables

How can I loop through a set of variables which are numbered consecutively (Bay1, Bay2, Bay3, etc.)?

I have 10 variables and I need to examine each variable with an If-Then statement and depending on the value of the variable assign three unique item numbers to each variable/iteration.

Possibly I would need to create an array or similar structure to store the item numbers for each iteration. I am unsure and I don't have any experience working with arrays.

Comment: Several options, including a `Scripting.Dictionary`, or one array, `Dim Bays(1 to 10) As Long` or something similar.

Comment: You have the architecture which is the hard part. Coding is easy. Just search here for arrays or google.

Comment: How do I loop through the Bay variables?

Comment: In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61637361)

Comment: This is used as an example in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417354/should-asking-syntax-related-questions-always-lead-to-a-not-enough-research-don).

Answer (score -1):

You better use a collection Object or the dictionary. Keep in mind that for using the dictionary, you have to reference the library first.

You could also use the `createObject()` method to create a dictionary Object, but using the reference will support you with intelisense functionality and a kind of type safety.

The last example is how to loop trough an array.

1. Dictionary Example
2. Collection Example
3. Array Example
4. Class Example

#### Code

```
Option Explicit


' -------------------------------------------------
'   Example using a Collection object.
Public Sub ShowExample_Collection()

    ' Get some Variables with initialized values
    Dim var1 As Integer: var1 = 11
    Dim var2 As Integer: var2 = 22
    Dim var3 As Integer: var3 = 33
    Dim var4 As Integer: var4 = 44
    Dim var5 As Integer: var5 = 55

    ' Store all of them inside of a collection
    Dim theCollection As New Collection
    Call theCollection.Add(var1)
    Call theCollection.Add(var2)
    Call theCollection.Add(var3)
    Call theCollection.Add(var4)
    Call theCollection.Add(var5)

    ' Now you can for each loop
    Dim intCheckVar As Integer
    Dim cntItem As Integer
    For cntItem = 1 To theCollection.Count
        intCheckVar = theCollection.Item(cntItem)
        ' Do something
        If intCheckVar < 30 Then
            Debug.Print "Variable number " & cntItem & " is lower than 30"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Variable number " & cntItem & " is higher than 30"
        End If

    Next

End Sub



' -------------------------------------------------
'   Example using a dictionary object.
'   Before using, you have to reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
Public Sub showExample_Dictionary()

    ' Before you can use the Dictionary Object, you have to 
    ' reference the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library
    Dim theDic As New Dictionary

    ' Get your Variables
    Dim var1 As Integer: var1 = 11
    Dim var2 As Integer: var2 = 22
    Dim var3 As Integer: var3 = 33
    Dim var4 As Integer: var4 = 44
    Dim var5 As Integer: var5 = 55

    ' Using a Dictionary is like using a collection.
    ' But you are able to set each item an unique Name
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_1", var1)
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_2", var2)
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_3", var3)
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_4", var4)
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_5", var5)

    ' You still can use a for each loop. But this time you can get the unique name
    ' of each item
    Dim intCheckVar As Integer
    Dim cntItem As Integer
    ' Dictionary is starting at index 0 !!
    For cntItem = 0 To theDic.Count - 1

        ' You can get the Value of the item using the items property of the dictionary object
        ' You can get the unique name of the item using the keys property of the dictionary object
        If theDic.Items(cntItem) < 30 Then
            Debug.Print "Variable with the name " & theDic.Keys(cntItem) & " is lower then 30"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Variable with the name " & theDic.Keys(cntItem) & " is higher then 30"
        End If

    Next

End Sub


' -------------------------------------------------
'   Example using a array.
Public Sub showExample_Array()

    ' Create your array
    Dim aVars(4) As Integer
    aVars(0) = 11
    aVars(1) = 22
    aVars(2) = 33
    aVars(3) = 44
    aVars(4) = 55

    ' You can loop through an array, but your pointing variable has to be of the datatpy variant
    Dim theVar As Variant
    Dim cntItem As Integer: cntItem = -1
    For Each theVar In aVars
        cntItem = cntItem + 1
        If theVar < 30 Then
            Debug.Print "Variable Number " & cntItem & " is lower than 30 because its value is " & theVar
        Else
            Debug.Print "Variable Number " & cntItem & " is higher than 30 because its value is " & theVar
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

You can also *store* your three *values* in an own class, and storing its Object inside of your iterating dictionary. The following code shows the class definition and the example code.

```
class cls_Data
   Public Data1 As Integer
   Public Data2 As Integer
   Public Data3 As Integer
end class


Public Sub showExample_Class()

    ' Before you can use the Dictionary Object, you have to reference the
    ' "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" Lib
    Dim theDic As New Dictionary

    ' Get your Variables
    Dim var1 As New cls_Data
    var1.Data1 = 11
    var1.Data2 = 12
    var1.Data3 = 13

    Dim var2 As New cls_Data
    var2.Data1 = 21
    var2.Data2 = 22
    var2.Data3 = 23

    Dim var3 As New cls_Data
    var3.Data1 = 31
    var3.Data2 = 32
    var3.Data3 = 33


    ' Using a Dictionary is like using a collection.
    ' But you are able to set each item an unique Name
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_1", var1)
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_2", var2)
    Call theDic.Add("Variable_3", var3)

    ' You still can use a for each loop. But this time
    ' you can get the unique name of each item
    Dim intCheckVar As Integer
    Dim cntItem As Integer
    ' Dictionary is starting at index 0!!
    For cntItem = 0 To theDic.Count - 1
        ' Get the reference of your stored values to have easier access
        Dim checkVar As cls_Data
        Set checkVar = theDic.Items(cntItem)
        ' Now you can check the data values of your referenced object and change it
        If checkVar.Data1 < 30 Then
            checkVar.Data1 = 100
            checkVar.Data2 = 200
            checkVar.Data3 = 300
        Else
            checkVar.Data1 = -100
            checkVar.Data2 = -200
            checkVar.Data3 = -300
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Within the loop when the If-Then statement is true I need to assign 3 different unique identifiers to each Bay. What type of structure could I use to store these 3 identifiers for each Bay? If intCheckVar(1) < 10 Then Bay(1) is (1011,2021,3031). If intCheckVar(2) > 10 And intCheckVar(2) < 20 Then Bay(2) is (1012,2022,3032) and so on...

Comment: You have to change the datatype of Var1to5 in my examples. Use an Integer Array. Or you can use collections/dictionaries either. That means, each item of your big collection is a collection itself (var1-5). What I really recommend you is to create an own class that is storing the three values. Then you can store in your big collection/dictionary items of this class.